# Toggle Icon for Accordion Nav

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried following an example found on SO and it's working like the example, except it's not (ie not actually changing the icon).

I've got an accordion navigation that has an icon by default, then it should toggle to another icon when open, then back to the original icon on close / new link in the nav clicked.

The accordion aspect is working just fine, it's the icon that's giving me issue.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nav-main > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // disable link
    $('.nav-main > li > a.active').next('.nav-main__sub').slideUp();

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) { // if NOT 'a.active'
      $(this).next('.nav-main__sub').slideToggle();

      $('.nav-main > li > a').find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-up').addClass('fa fa-angle-down');
      $(this).find('i').addClass('fa fa-angle-up');
      $('.nav-main > li > a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-up').addClass('fa fa-angle-down');
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/*
-------------------------
  Navigation
-------------------------
*/

.nav {

  font-family: "AvenirLT-Heavy", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

  font-size: 1.125rem;

}

.nav a {

  color: #00539b;

}

.nav a:hover {

  color: #f6b242;

}

.nav a i {

  color: #f6b242;

  vertical-align: baseline !important;

  font-weight: 700;

  float: right;

}

.nav-main > li {

  border-bottom: 1px solid #00539b;

  padding: 30px 0;

}

.nav-main > li:first-of-type {

  padding-top: 0;

}

.nav-main > li:last-of-type {

  border-bottom: none;

}

.nav-main > li > a {

  padding: 0 0 0.7rem;

}

.nav-main__sub {

  display: none;

  font-size: 0.9375rem;

  font-family: "AvenirLT-Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}

.nav-main__sub li > a {

  padding-left: 0;

}

/*
-------------------------
  Modules
-------------------------
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="vertical menu nav-main">
    <li><a href="#">Moving &amp; Relocation <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="/overview/">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Workplace Solutions <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Logistics <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Our Capacity <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Careers <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the class for `$(this)`, you also need to remove the arrow down class that you added to everything in the line above. So, after this line:

```
$(this).find('i').addClass('fa-angle-up');
```

Add this line:

```
$(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-down');
```

(Notice that I took out the class `fa` in `addClass` and `removeClass` because it doesn't need to get added or removed -- it stays the same.)

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrEVzq

Comment: Thanks! I figured as much on the single `fa` (it was in the example I was following)